# How can I activate a child window using Nircmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to use the utility program Nircmd to activate a window using a batch file.  I can easily activate a top-level window using:

```
nircmd win activate "titleofwindow"
```

But this does not work if the window is a child of a parent window.  My parent window is Trade-Ideas and it has lots of child windows.  I want to activate one of the child windows.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.  To activate the child window, I used the following command:

```
nircmd win activate title "titleofwindow"
```

So the piece that was missing was argument "title" between activate and the name of the window.

Comment: nircmd win activate title startswith match , how to?

Comment: nircmd win multi action